# Filter out n number of duplicates

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe such as follows:

| id | first_name | last_name | sex | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | John | Doe | Male | USA |
| 02 | John | Doe | Male | Canada |
| 03 | John | Doe | Male | Mexico |
| 04 | Mark | Kay | Male | Italy |
| 05 | John | Doe | Male | Spain |
| 06 | Mark | Kay | Male | France |
| 07 | John | Doe | Male | Peru |
| 08 | Mark | Kay | Male | India |
| 09 | Mark | Kay | Male | Laos |
| 10 | John | Doe | Male | Benin |

As you can see, the id and country columns are always unique, but the dataframe has duplicates based on columns first_name, last_name and sex. I want to be able to find such duplicates, and keep only upto 3 of them (ideally the last 3) and drop the rest. So after this operation, the resulting dataframe should look like this:

| id | first_name | last_name | sex | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05 | John | Doe | Male | Spain |
| 06 | Mark | Kay | Male | France |
| 07 | John | Doe | Male | Peru |
| 08 | Mark | Kay | Male | India |
| 09 | Mark | Kay | Male | Laos |
| 10 | John | Doe | Male | Benin |

How can I do this? Any help is appreciated!

I tried this:

```
window_spec = Window.partitionBy('first_name', 'last_name', 'sex').orderBy(F.desc('id'))
df_with_row_number = df.withColumn('row_number', F.row_number().over(window_spec))
filtered_df = df_with_row_number.filter('row_number <= 3')
result_df = filtered_df.drop('row_number')
```

This does give me the result I want. But I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve this, since it's a large dataset with a lot more rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the groupby method in your dataframe.
Here is an example :

```
import pandas as pd

# Your original dataframe
data = {
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'first_name': ['John', 'John', 'John', 'Mark', 'John', 'Mark', 'John', 'Mark', 'Mark', 'John'],
    'last_name': ['Doe', 'Doe', 'Doe', 'Kay', 'Doe', 'Kay', 'Doe', 'Kay', 'Kay', 'Doe'],
    'sex': ['Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male'],
    'country': ['USA', 'Canada', 'Mexico', 'Italy', 'Spain', 'France', 'Peru', 'India', 'Laos', 'Benin']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Sort the dataframe based on the 'id' column
df = df.sort_values(by='id')

# Keep only the last 3 occurrences for each group of first_name, last_name, and sex
result_df = df.groupby(['first_name', 'last_name', 'sex']).tail(3)

# Reset the index if needed
result_df = result_df.reset_index(drop=True)

# Display the resulting dataframe
print(result_df)
```

Which should output :

```
   id first_name last_name   sex country
0   5       John       Doe  Male   Spain
1   6       Mark       Kay  Male  France
2   7       John       Doe  Male    Peru
3   8       Mark       Kay  Male   India
4   9       Mark       Kay  Male    Laos
5  10       John       Doe  Male   Benin
```